# Override Makefile variable

Tags: makefile

Trying override `option_one` variable in Makefile from command line `make option_one=hi`. But output shows variable is not overridden. What I do wrong?

Makefile content:

```
override option_one = did_override
all: 
    echo $(option_one)
```

Command output:

```
echo did_override
did_override
```

Comment: Not so sure about `override`, but conditional assignment should work just fine: `option_one ?= my_default_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By ...

> Trying override `option_one` variable in Makefile from command line `make option_one=hi`

... you appear to mean that you want the value specified on the command line to be the one used, instead of the one specified in the makefile.  That is the **standard** behavior.  You have thwarted it by specifying `override` for the in-makefile assignment, which causes the assignment in the makefile to override any value given on the command line, exactly opposite to what you want.  Just drop that:

```
option_one = from_makefile
all: 
    echo $(option_one)
```

That yields:

```
> make
echo from_makefile
from_makefile

> make option_one=hi
echo hi
hi
```